# Match first occurrence of a string

Tags: java, regex

Example of string: `Alerts will be silent from 00:00 to 05:00`. The regex must match any sequence with following format `nn:nn` where `n` is a digit. No problem here, `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` works perfectly. The aim however is to identify separately each sequence`00:00` and `05:00`. The `00:00` and `05:00`represent hours, the reason I need to identify them separately is because string must be updated with relevant hours.

The following regex works to match `05:00`: `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$`. However for the first sequence `00:00` the only way I was able to make it work is `\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\s`, which matches `00:00` but with whitespaces at both ends. Of course this is not desired result, the sequence must be matched without whitespaces.

Comment: `The aim however is to identify separately each sequence` can you expand on that?

Comment: You do not have to match them separately, you may capture them - [`\b([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\b.*\b([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})$`](https://regex101.com/r/ggdAA8/1). Certainly, you may use [`\b([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(?!$)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ggdAA8/2) to exclude a match at the end of the string. Or with lookarounds - [`(?<=\s)[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}(?=\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/ggdAA8/3).

Comment: As I see many times, this could be easily done without regex (substringing)

Comment: I guess the downvote is related to your question tagging and the nature of the question - it does not sound like your approach is right and it sounds as if you are not telling us what you are really doing. If you provide the code you have that does not work as expected, it would be much clearer. Does [`(?<=\s)[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}(?=\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/ggdAA8/3)  do what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew \b([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(?!$)\b and (?<=\s)[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}(?=\s) works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Rogue, each problem has several ways to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem can be solved in a different way, but you only provided few details.

Addressing the main issue, mainly:

> the sequence must be matched without whitespaces

note that `\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\s` contains `\s` as part of the *consuming* pattern. To just check if the whitespaces are present or absent, you should use *lookarounds*, or *zero-width assertions*.

```
(?<=\s)[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}(?=\s)
```

Here, `(?<=\s)` requires the presence of a whitespace before the first  1 or 2 digits, but it does not consume this whitespace. `(?=\s)` positive lookahead requires the presence of a whitespace after the trailing 1 or 2  digits, and is not consumed either.

By "consumed" I mean the matched substring does not make part of the returned match value.